# Animation is not working after the Home button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a game that has an animated background for the title screen. The animation used is simply a `CGMoveToPoint` function that moves the image back and forth.

This works perfectly on the simulator, except, when testing on a real device pressing the home button and then re-opening the app, the animation of this image doesn't move.

I was hoping there would be a simple fix. I was thinking something along the lines of a memory issue and using the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` function, but I am very inexperienced with this or when to use it.

I am targeting iOS 5.1 in my build.

Comment: where you add the code for this animation...??

Answer (score 1):

Just add the Animation code in `viewWillAppear:` method instead of `viewDidLoad:` method..

Comment: the code is in the viewDidLoad: method at the moment for the view.

Comment: yes but if you want to do this animation when you open that class every time then it must write this code in viewWillAppear method..

Comment: Ok so I've moved it into viewWillAppear, same thing happens. Animation works all the time, until the you goto the home screen and then back to the app.

Comment: solved it.
added Application does not run in background to the .plist forcing the app to reload each time. I didn't want my app to run in the background anyway, so this is a very neat solution.

Comment: @SamBo oh ok ok very good mate.. happy new year and enjoy the coding and here i give this idea bcoz some time user want to animation when he enetr in any view and also update the data when he push in the viewController so i give this idea.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want your app to run in the background, then adding the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key ("Application does not run in background") to the plist file will work. [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

However, if you do want your app to run in the background, then I suggest using `NSNotificationCenter`. [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html)

For example, add the following line to your class's `init` or `viewDidLoad` method:

**Objective-C**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

**Swift**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationWillEnterForeground:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

Then add the following method to you class:

**Objective-C**

```
- (void) applicationWillEnterForeground {
     // add code here to restart animation
}
```

**Swift**

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification) {
    // add code here to restart animation
}
```

Note, `viewWillAppear` will not always (if ever) be called when an application enters the foreground after being in the background. So I wouldn't rely on using it to restart the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your animation

`animation.removedOnCompletion = false;`